# Configure plugin in grails 2.2.4

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

My project plugin code block :

```
plugins {
    compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"
    compile ":jasper:1.6.1"
    compile ":mail:1.0.1"
    compile ":executor:0.3"
    compile ":jcaptcha:1.2.1"

    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
}
```

But when I project the below error message shows in console :

Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- :spring-security-core:1.2.7.3
- :jasper:1.6.1
- :mail:1.0.1
- :executor:0.3
- :jcaptcha:1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Sometime in the last few years, the location of the default grails repo changed.  Try adding this to your `repositories` block:

```
mavenRepo(root:"https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins", name:"newGrailsCentral")
```

PS: why are you using 2.2.4?  If you're starting a new project, as your question implies, then you should use 2.4.5 or 3.0.1 if you possibly can.